# How increase vue cli3 production build speed?

Tags: vue.js, build, vue-cli-3

I want to build a Vue web app in production with minimum time for live preview purpose, I think we can achieve this by avoiding unwanted file optimizations like compressing,chunks creation etc. How we config the Vue cli3 for faster build system?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to get feedback from code changes is to run the app in HMR mode with:

```
vue-cli-service serve
```

That's normally only used in development though.  Could you explain further what you're changing in production and why you're waiting for it to rebuild in production? Are you perhaps building an app from a set of user-selected components and you want the fastest build time possible to demo the app to the user?

Comment: I don't want  `vue-cli-service serve ` because it will consume more resource (for live server file watch etc).